# Best way to parse a file with columns that randomly change order before importing it into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: python, perl, sql-server-2008, parsing

I have a file that has columns that look like this:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
Column1,Column3,Column2,Column6,Column5,Column4
1,3,2,6,5,4
1,3,2,6,5,4
1,3,2,6,5,4
Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column1
2,3,4,5,6,1
2,3,4,5,6,1
2,3,4,5,6,1
```

The columns randomly re-order in the middle of the file, and the only way to know the order is to look at the last set of headers right before the data (Column1,Column2, etc.)  (I've also simplified the data so that it's easier to picture.  In real life, there is no way to tell data apart as they are all large integer values that could really go into any column)

Obviously this isn't very SQL Server friendly when it comes to using BULK INSERT, so I need to find a way to arrange all of the columns in a consistent order that matches my table's column order in my SQL database.  What's the best way to do this?  I've heard Python is the language to use, but I have never worked with it. Any suggestions/sample scripts in any language are appreciated.

Comment: What problem have you encountered? (aka: SO is not a code writing service)

Comment: Two questions: 1. should this be a completely autonomous batch job running on the SQL or are you going to do this one time only? 2. How many changes are there in the file approximately?

Comment: ikegami: I can't import this file into my SQL server right now because the data goes into the wrong columns like this.  You can't program BULK INSERT to rearrange columns in the middle of running it.

Comment: I plan on importing this data daily, but I don't need to do it all in SQL.  I am okay with using some other script/program to first fix the formatting/arrangement and then I would be okay with importing the final file using a SQL job.

Comment: The file has approximately 10,000 rows.  The number of switches between columns can be completely random.  It can be absolutely zero, or it can be as high as 20 re-orderings of the column headers.

Comment: You might take a look at (for perl) Text::CSV's column_names, and simply check if a line contains a column name, and if it does, call column_names with the new row. Then proceed as usual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution in python:

I would read line-by-line and look for headers.  When I find a header, I use it to figure out the order (somehow).  Then I pass that order to `itemgetter` which will do the magic of reordering elements:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def header_parse(line,order_dict):
    header_info = line.split(',')
    indices = [None] * len(header_info)
    for i,col_name in enumerate(header_info):
        indices[order_dict[col_name]] = i
    return indices

def fix(fname,foutname):
    with open(fname) as f,open(foutname,'w') as fout:
        #Assume first line is a "header" and gives the order to use for the
        #rest of the file
        line = f.readline()
        order_dict = dict((name,i) for i,name in enumerate(line.strip().split(',')))
        reorder_magic = itemgetter(*header_parse(line.strip(),order_dict))
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('Column'):  #somehow determine if this is a "header"
                reorder_magic = itemgetter(*header_parse(line.strip(),order_dict))
            else:
                fout.write(','.join(reorder_magic(line.strip().split(','))) + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    fix(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Now you can call it as:

```
python fixscript.py badfile goodfile
```

Comment: May I ask what language this is in?

Comment: @eek142 -- python.  If you want it to be a commandline script, we can do that... 1 minute ...

Comment: I think you are right about having to go through line by line.  I'm okay with it using CPU resources to do this, as I plan to run this overnight.

Comment: It's amazing how people just start upvoting when they see a reasonably high rep user answer something.  My previous answer was a bit buggy, but the new answer should work OK.  You said your original file has 10000 rows.  This should run in a couple seconds or less.  Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: @mgilson you are relying on column having a integer for sorting, that may not work in all cases, I think OP just gave a sample

Comment: @AnuragUniyal -- Yes, but only in the parse_header function.  Since I don't know the column names, I had to do *something* to order them.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal -- No longer has that restriction -- Now we assume that the first line is a header and we preserve that order for the rest of the file

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this to run.  I have a sample csv file named "bad_test.csv" that I just created to test this out.  When I type in "python fixscript.py bad_test.csv > good_test.csv" it throws a syntax error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All I did was save the script as fixscript.py in the Python GUI.  Did I miss a step?

Comment: @eek142 -- where is the syntax error?  It's possible I lost a parenthesis or something ... (but it seems to work for me).  What system are you on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.  How do I run this command?  I basically just opened a command prompt and navigated to the directory where the script and test file are, and then I ran your command.  The error is: File "<stdin>", line 1, in ? Invalid Syntax

Comment: @eek142 -- I think you're entering the `python fixscript.py datafile > fixeddatafile` command at the *python* prompt.  You need to enter that command from the *Windows* prompt -- but I don't know how to do that since I don't use Windows.

Comment: it's throwing a different error now that I changed the default application for handling .py files.  Here is the new error: `C:\Python27>python fixscript.py bad_file.csv > fixed_file.csv
  File "fixscript.py", line 1
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
 win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  It's actually generating a `fixed_file.csv`, but it's blank.  So I think I'm getting closer...

Comment: I don't think that's what you want to do.  Try this.  Open a python interactive prompt.  type `print "hello"` -- If it says "hello" back, you're in business.  Then you can do `import os; os.system("python fixscript.py bad_file > good_file")`.  See if that works.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to find and run `cmd.exe`.  Then you type the python command in there...

Comment: Same results.  The new file is blank and it throws a syntaxerror in the command prompt.  Do I have to add any code to the script?

Comment: @eek142 -- It should work I think.  I've updated though to avoid the shell re-direction.  Now the script should write directly to the output file you specify -- e.g. `os.system('python fixscript.py badfile goodfile')` -- Sorry I don't know much about windows ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18520/discussion-between-eek142-and-mgilson)

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed easily in two steps:

- split file into multiple files when a new header starts
- read each file using csv dict reader, sort the keys and re-output rows in correct order

Here is an example how you can ho about it,

```
def is_header(line):
    return line.find('Column') >= 0

def process(lines):  
    headers = None
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if is_header(line):
            headers = list(enumerate(line.split(",")))
            headers_map = dict(headers)
            headers.sort(key=lambda (i,v):headers_map[i])
            print ",".join([h for i,h in headers])
            continue

        values = list(enumerate(line.split(",")))
        values.sort(key=lambda (i,v):headers_map[i])
        print ",".join([v for i,v in values])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    process(open(sys.argv[1]))
```

You can also change function `is_header` to correctly identify header in real cases

Comment: Is there a program I can use to split the file?

Comment: @eek142 you can try this script, it should work as it is, also it doesn't rely on column having any specific integers or structure

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't mention a specific problem, I'm going to assume you're having problems coming up with an algorithm.

1. For each row,

   1. Parse the row into fields.
   2. If it's the first header line,

      1. Output the header.
      2. Create a map of field names to position.

         ```
         %map = map { $fields[$_] => $_ } 0..$#fields;
         ```
      3. Create a map of original positions to new positions.

         ```
         @map = @map{ @fields };
         ```
   3. If it's a header line other than the first,

      1. Update map of original positions to new positions.

         ```
         @map = @map{ @fields };
         ```
   4. If it's not a header line,

      1. Reorder fields.

         ```
         @fields[ @map ] = @fields;
         ```
      2. Output the row.

(Snippets are in Perl.)